# undefined method error with delete statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For my projects I have the following relevant code

routes:

```
resources :lists do
  resources :items
end
```

I now included a loop on list/show page in which I want to show the item and provide the users with the possibility to delete the item.

So i got code like this:

```
<% @items.each do |item|%>
  <p> 
    Item: <%= item.name %> 
    <%= time_ago_in_words(item.created_at) %> ago. 
  </p> 
  <%= link_to "Delete", [@list.item, item], method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

But when I try to run it I get the error:

`undefined method 'item' for #<List:0x007fba7be6fe28>`

While I did define the variables in my controller:

Items-controller:

```
def destroy
  @list = current_user.list
  @item = @list.items
end
```

Could anyone explain whats causing this error?

Comment: please show the code of your *show* action as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a typo in your controller - it should be `@items = @list.items` that's why the iteration doesn't work properly.

edit: after formatting your original question, I see that the error was raised on `@list` object, so you have to fix path to `delete` action:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", [@list, item], method: :delete %>
```

you build the path by providing the parent object (`@list`) and then the object itself (`item`) - Rails will translate it to `list_item_path`.

Answer (score -1):

You're using `@items.each` and in your controller have only `@item`.

Comment: From how I understand his code, he's on the index action and wants to call delete. So @items defined on index is correct.

Comment: that may be the right thing,  but he should provide all the require code

Comment: yep, asked him to do so.

Answer (score -1):

change your link_to

```
= link_to("Delete", lists_items_url(@list, @item), method: :delete)
```

You have defined resources :lists and resources :items.
Basically what you want to do is send a DELETE request to the collection with the IDs to fetch and delete the items.

Run a ***rake routes*** to check the exact naming, but I think it's written like that to be sure. Although you don't seem to be needing the IDs based on your controller's action, you still need to supply them for the helper.